# How to draw multiple boxplot from one csv

Tags: pgfplots, boxplot

I have 3 CSV files (teapot.csv, cube.csv, and sphere.csv)

They all look like that :

```
duration,x,y,z,norm
13506,0.763489,0.21941,0.571625,0.978678365
25162,1.466019,-0.222542,1.588425,2.172977365
9083,1.901184,-0.977882,1.170418,2.437341195
10622,1.819077,-0.501896,1.038895,2.154122454
13370,2.756989,-0.097477,1.579063,3.178667971
[many more lines]
```

I would like to have a graph that look like this one (even without the mean values) :
[image]

This graph was obtained with a boxplot prepared which force me to precompute every value and enter them manually. I have multiple similar graphs to draw and this is a method I want to avoid.

So I try something like that :

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
        width=13cm,
        height=8cm,
    }
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={distance (cm)}, 
    title={Location comparison}, 
    ytick={1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10,11,13,14,15},
    yticklabels={\textcolor{red}{teapot},
        delta X \quad \textcolor{green}{cube}, 
        \textcolor{blue}{sphere},
        \textcolor{red}{teapot},
        delta Y \quad \textcolor{green}{cube}, 
        \textcolor{blue}{sphere},
        \textcolor{red}{teapot},
        delta Z \quad \textcolor{green}{cube}, 
        \textcolor{blue}{sphere},
        \textcolor{red}{teapot},
        norm \quad \textcolor{green}{cube}, 
        \textcolor{blue}{sphere}
    }
]
% delta X
\addplot [mark = *, mark options = {red}, 
    boxplot={draw position=1}, 
    color = red
    ] table[x=x,col sep=comma] {Figures/csv/teapot.csv};
\addplot [ 
    boxplot={draw position=2}, 
    color = green
    ] table[x=x,col sep=comma] {Figures/csv/cube.csv};
\addplot [ 
    boxplot={draw position=3}, 
    color = blue
    ] table[x=x,col sep=comma] {Figures/csv/sphere.csv};
    
% delta Y
\addplot [mark = *, mark options = {red}, 
    boxplot={draw position=5}, 
    color = red
    ] table[x=y,col sep=comma] {Figures/csv/teapot.csv};
\addplot [ 
    boxplot={draw position=6}, 
    color = green
    ] table[x=y,col sep=comma] {Figures/csv/cube.csv};
\addplot [ 
    boxplot={draw position=7}, 
    color = blue
    ] table[x=y,col sep=comma] {Figures/csv/sphere.csv};
    
% delta Z  
\addplot [mark = *, mark options = {red}, 
    boxplot={draw position=9}, 
    color = red
    ] table[x=z,col sep=comma] {Figures/csv/teapot.csv};
\addplot [ 
    boxplot={draw position=10}, 
    color = green
    ] table[x=z,col sep=comma] {Figures/csv/cube.csv};
\addplot [ 
    boxplot={draw position=11}, 
    color = blue
    ] table[x=z,col sep=comma] {Figures/csv/sphere.csv};
 
% norm
\addplot [mark = *, mark options = {red}, 
    boxplot={draw position=13}, 
    color = red
    ] table[x=norm,col sep=comma] {Figures/csv/teapot.csv};
\addplot [ 
    boxplot={draw position=14}, 
    color = green
    ] table[x=norm,col sep=comma] {Figures/csv/cube.csv};
\addplot [ 
    boxplot={draw position=15}, 
    color = blue
    ] table[x=norm,col sep=comma] {Figures/csv/sphere.csv};  
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And I obtain this graph :
[image]

I have 4 times the same block of graphs. The one related to the x column of CSV is correct, but all the others are just copies from this first block.

How to solve this?

Comment: Welcome and +1 for the interesting question. Tip: You can use the ´filecontents´ environment to create the csv files on the fly so that people here can test your code without modification. See https://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents (but in modern LaTeX versions the ´filecontents´ environment can be used without a package).